# Storing LDAP password in django session

Tags: django, ldap, password-encryption

So I know it is really **BAD PRACTICE** to store a users password in cleartext (even encrypted)....But here is my problem.

I am developing an in-house automation web-app using django as my backend and users login using their LDAP credentials. My app interacts with several 3rd party applications (Jira, Jenkins, Gitlab) that also use ldap credentials for user authentication. I would also like the ability to write to the users (linux) file system from the server (saving generated scripts).

What are my options?

The only one i have though of is to encrypt the password when user logs in and store that in the django session. Encryption and decryption keys will be generated per session and saved using django's sessions. The password will be decrypted whenever a password is needed but it will never be saved as clear text

*Obviously the user will need to concent to this method

Any other ideas?

Comment: Just wondered what your solution was for this problem? I am facing the exact same issues!

Answer (score 0):

If we're saying about logging into user's account using SSH, you can use public/private keys to do that. When user logs in, use his password for connecting to his account and create here `authorized_keys` file (or edit existing one) inside `~/.ssh` directory. That way you will have access to SSH later.

Additionally, you can create some scripts that will handle that filesystem changes on root level.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Jira and Gitlab can use OAuth and I'm pretty sure Jenkins understands that also. So you might be able to generate an OAuth-Token for the user on login (when you have the password in cleartext) for those systems and then use that token without the need to store the password.

Regarding the SSH-Access @GwynBleidD already gave a good answer.